# Training inputs in keras

Tags: python, neural-network, stanford-nlp, keras

I have word-vectors(Glove vectors) pre trained over general twitter dataset. I have a set of tweets and I want to retrain the word-vectors parallelly with the task in hand. This requires updating the inputs in the MLP. How do I retrain input in sequential MLP in keras?

Edit :
Glove pre-trained(on twitter) vector are already provided on their website . I have some users and their tweets and I have a classification task . So I am trying to convert words of the tweets into wordvectors and taking their average to get word vector representation of tweet. But as adopted in standard literature , I want to retrain the wordvectors on the new network(Word vectors are inputs now). How can I implement this in keras

Comment: Do you already have a pre-trained network or simply its outputs (output vectors)? If you have the network, you could simply use "fit" or train_on _batch methods over your trained Model.  Otherwise you could try a workaround such as using the original words as inputs and minimizing the MSE error to your word-vectors to generate an approximated network.

Comment: Please see the edit . (It did not fit into a comment)